# want link in iframe src to open in same window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have reviewed all questions retrieved in the search that might have helped me.

I'm working in DHTML (Perl, CSS, and JavaScript) on Windows 7 using IE 11.   webpage/Program 1 dynamically generates a complete webpage/program 2 and writes it to disk.  An iframe in program 1 then executes that code as its SRC.  All works well to this point and can be seen with the link below.

http://steepusa.no-ip.info/scx/l3menu.cgi?l3mstr=SKY:Pollution:2:level3:2003/43.0/7.00/0.38B

When I click on a blue circle, like Food, 3 yellow circles appear that are links, as expected.
All 3 links work as intended EXCEPT all three links open in a new window.  I want the links to open in the same window that program 1 is executing in.  The 3 yellow circle links I generate for the page your viewing follow.

```
<A href='javascript:location.href="http://steepusa.no-ip.info/scx/level1.cgi?str=SKY:Pollution-Air:2:level3";' ONMOUSEOVER="setStatus('  ');" ONMOUSEOUT="setStatus('  ');">Measure Profile</A>

<A href='javascript:window.top.location.href=("http://steepusa.no-ip.info/scx/level1.cgi?str=SKY:Pollution-Air:3:level3");' ONMOUSEOVER="setStatus('  ');" ONMOUSEOUT="setStatus('  ');">Behavior Summary</A>

<A href='javascript:window.open("http://steepusa.no-ip.info/scx/shoabrdg.cgi?str=SKY:Pollution-Air:e2","_self","",false);' ONMOUSEOVER="setStatus('  ');" ONMOUSEOUT="setStatus('  ');">Effort Analysis</A>
```

I've tried the 3 approaches in these links and other variations to see what would happen, like parent.location.href and self.location.href.   I've also tried the straight HTML approach where HREF is simply the link and a target id specified as a base or in the link is used, and I've tried _blank, _self, _parent, and _top just to see what would happen.  All approaches open in a new window.

Thank you for your time,
craigt

added - > The screen dynamics of the link above are generated using SVG/VML vector graphics.  Might there be some interaction with this graphics function and the way the anchors above open in a new window?

Comment: just setting the url string as href and doing nothing else , default behavior is to load url in same window

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: I found the problem.   It was in the SVG/VML vector graphics function.   The link was be executed with _blank.  I changed it to top and it works.   Thank you all for looking and your comment.

Comment: figured it had to be something like that